# Twitter API: reconnection for TCP/IP level network errors

Tags: api, twitter

I'm working on a backoff strategy for a robot that connects through the **Twitter Streaming API**.  The API documentation states:

> Back off linearly for TCP/IP level network errors. These problems are generally temporary and tend to clear quickly. Increase the delay in reconnects by 250ms each attempt, up to 16 seconds.

I understand this errors to be when – for whatever reason – the client cannot communicate with the server (ie: no Internet service).  However, I'm not sure if **HTTP status codes equal or greater than 500** should be treated as **TCP/IP level network errors** too (ie: 503 service unavailable), because, in order to receive this error codes, a successful connection between client and server should have happened already.

Could someone please help me understand this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this post earned me a "Tumbleweed" badge :-), I decided to post the reply I received at [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/20479):

> **@kurrik**
>
> I think your intuition is correct in that a HTTP status code is not a TCP/IP error and you should use the exponential backoff. The slower backoff for these kinds of errors is so that your connection does not get rate limited. A 5XX error is a bit unusual, as it indicates an error which may have happened before or after the connection attempt was logged by the rate limiter. To be safe, I'd say use exponential backoff for this case (although most 503 issues should be cleared after the first reconnect attempt).

I ended up using this strategy:

- *Disconnections and 500 errors:* linear backoff starting at 0.25s and adding 0.25s each time, up to 16s.
- *All errors greater than 500:* exponential backoff starting at 5s and doubling the amount each time, up to 5 minutes.
- *Rate limited (420 / 429):* exponential backoff starting at 1m and doubling the amount each time.
- *No reconnection:*  all 4XX errors different from the rate limit errors.